# DD-WRT flashed router is not prompting for a password whenever a PC tries to connect to a network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

So installed dd-wrt on my ASUS RT-N66U, everything seems to be working fine with it except that whenever a PC wants to connect to my network it is not asked for a password. I already set up my wireless security for WPA2 Personal with AES encryption, but it still does not request a password whenever someone wants to connect to my network. Although it did ask for a password whenever there was a phone trying to get connected.

I'm very new at using custom firmware, this is actually the first time I've flashed a router. I've also tried connecting to the router with TELNET but it says I'm using the wrong login when I know I'm not, it works fine on the browser GUI.

Used this guide to perform the installation, given that it was the latest one I could find.

http://www.mysolutions.it/install-dd-wrt-asus-rt-n66u/

I used DD-WRT v3.0-r27360 (06/18/15) big, hope it doesn't have any bugs or anything.

Comment: The machines you're connecting, have they ever connected before? They aren't just remembering the password from before? Can they actually get a connection without entering a password? Telnet usually uses the login of root, with the password you set.

Comment: Note - I'm using the same version on my router with WPA2 AES and have no problems, a different model router though.

Comment: They connected before when I was using the stock Asus firmware and yes I used my root password but it still doesn't want to let me connect through Telnet. Everything that uses the network is basically everyone's devices in my home. However I know my network can be seen in the neighboring houses, not that I think they're going to steal my wifi, but I just don't want some random stranger draining my internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the same SSID and password as before with the same security settings, then they'll carry on using the same credentials without a problem. Depending on your OS, you can remove the credentials they are remembering to make sure the security is working correctly.

Some links to the most used OS's here:

[Remove remembered wireless networks in Windows 7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252588(v=ws.10).aspx)

[Remove remembered wireless networks in Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/manage-wireless-network-profiles)

[Remove remembered wireless networks in Windows 10](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/forget-wireless-network-profiles-windows-10)

[Remove remembered wireless networks in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/09/forget-wifi-network-mac-os-x/)

Try removing the network from your remembered networks and connecting again. It should then prompt you for the PSK.

As for telnet into your device, the username will be `root`, not the username you've set for web login. The password, however, will be the same.

```
DD-WRT v3.0-r27506 std (c) 2015 NewMedia-NET GmbH
Release: 07/09/15

DD-WRT login: root
Password: #######
==========================================================

     ___  ___     _      _____  ______       ____  ___
    / _ \/ _ \___| | /| / / _ \/_  __/ _  __|_  / / _ \
   / // / // /___/ |/ |/ / , _/ / /   | |/ //_ <_/ // /
  /____/____/    |__/|__/_/|_| /_/    |___/____(_)___/

                       DD-WRT v3.0
                   http://www.dd-wrt.com

==========================================================


BusyBox v1.23.2 (2015-07-09 02:27:16 CEST) built-in shell (ash)

root@DD-WRT:~#
```

Comment: Yes that did it, on both counts. Thanks for the help.